# jquery .on itself

Tags: javascript, events, jquery

I want an element to listen for a custom event that is actually triggered by itself. The custom event could possibly be triggered from a descendant but should then be ignored. It's important that it origins from itself. It also needs to be an event since I might need additional ancestors to listen for the events.

The .on (http://api.jquery.com/on/) method is able to provide this functionality. The selector argument can be used as filter. However this does **not** work to filter out the listener element itself.

In short:
-The event must be able to bubble
-The trigger and the listener is the same element
-The listener must ignore the custom event if it's triggered by an ancestors

How is this achieved?

**Use case as requested**

I use the jquery UI dialog widget

```
$el = $('#dialogDiv');
$el.on('customEvent', $el /* Won't work */, function() {
    //Do whatever
});
$el.dialog({
    open: function() {
        $el.trigger('customEvent');
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your use case?

Comment: An event will always pass by an element's ancestors before it gets to the element, that's just how the DOM works. I am not sure what you mean by "trigger" here.

Comment: Cant you make the trigger and the on both just call a function and send the function the 'this'

Comment: If you want the event to fire for only one element, why are you trying to use delegation? Just bind the listener directly to the element.

Comment: @Asad I hope the code snippet I added helps clarifying the question. Maybe I have to assign the trigger to an ancestor of #dialogDiv, but's since it's not a single case I rather find a method that is easy to understand and implement over and over again

Comment: @Jack Updated the question per request.

Comment: @Anders Thanks, though still unclear my updated answer could help.

Comment: @Asad Would I be able to filter out custom events with the same name originating from any ancestor that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.on` works fine; to ignore ancestors check `e.target`:

```
$el.on('customEvent', function(e) {
  if(e.target === this) {
    //Do whatever
  }
});
```

Comment: @Anders: Sure, the object is not cloned or something. A custom trigger also sets `e.target` appropriately so this should work fine.

Comment: Alright then. I think I'll write a simple wrapper plugin to implement this. Like .onMyself() or something. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: That comparison will always fail. `$el` is a jQuery set, not the actual element. You want `if (e.target === this)` instead. Not sure how this is at all relevant to his question though.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the part that doesn't work, will make it work.

```
$el = $('#dialogDiv');
$el.on('customEvent', function(e) {
    //Do whatever
});
$el.dialog({
    open: function() {
        $el.trigger('customEvent');
    }
});
```

However, you are asking for other features that a normal event might not support. You should look into setting up a [jQuery special event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#Special_Events). Check [this awesome article by Ben Alman](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/).

When it comes to your prerequisites:

- An event is always able to bubble unless its propagation is hindered with `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`
- The trigger and the listener is already on the same element
- The listener will not know what triggered it unless you pass some an argument that can identify the element that triggered it and check if it's an ancestor

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8HYC/2).

Comment: Won't this actually capture any event named 'customEvent' from any descendant element as well? I will read through the article to see if any ideas arise. Points to you

Comment: @Anders I've updated my answer with a small test case that I hope will help :)

Comment: Thank you Marcus. pimvdb nailed it though. [Further reading](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) supports his answer

Comment: @Anders Problem is, triggering the event on the descendants is not possible unless you delegate it. So checking `e.target` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Anders I've updated my test case so that it also delegates the event to all descendants.

Comment: I'm not to familiar with jsFiddle, but I've tried to save my changes. It's the third test case (at the bottom) that I'm looking for. I've added a selection in the function to capture the case as well. You might have misunderstood me or I might not been entirely clear what I've meant earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The selector that you can pass to `.on()` is used for the delegate target to match elements that can handle the click event (and it should be a string, not an object).

But in your case that's not necessary because your selector and the delegate target is the same thing, so this should work as expected:

```
$el.on('customEvent', function(evt) {
    //Do whatever
});
```

To detect if an event came from a descendent you would compare `evt.target` against the element itself.

Comment: Won't this actually capture any event named 'customEvent' from any descendant element as well?

Comment: Note that `targetElement` is not set for custom events.

Comment: @pimvdb Yeah, I wasn't sure about that one ;-)