# Call function on jQuery show()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to call a function when a div is shown.  Based on code at http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-trigger-custom-event-show-hide-element/ it is mostly working.  The problem that I have is that my show() function is being called even when something inside my main div is being shown.  I am attaching the event to the main div, so was expecting it would only fire when the main div was shown.  But even if a sub-element inside the main_div is shown, the even fires.  How can I prevent this?

Here is the meat of the code:

```
(function ($) {
    $.each(['show', 'hide'], function (i, ev) {
        var el = $.fn[ev];
        $.fn[ev] = function () {
            this.trigger(ev);
            return el.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    });
})(jQuery);

// I only want this to be called when main_div is shown, not sub_div
$('#main_div').on('show', function () {
    $('#console').html($('#console').html() + this.id + ' is visible' + '<br>');
});

// I only want this to be called when main_div is hidden, not sub_div
$('#main_div').on('hide', function () {
    $('#console').html($('#console').html() + this.id + ' is hidden' + '<br>');
});
```

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/jon_harris7/975wJ/42/

Comment: simply using css add `display:none` to both div's then when the page loads it won't be visible. http://jsfiddle.net/975wJ/41/

Comment: Thanks Magma, but the hiding was just an example.  The larger question is how to deal with the event bubbling, not hiding/showing in particular.

Comment: I was going to answer the question, but apparently I can't because it has been marked as a duplicate.  At any rate, I figured out how to ignore the events I don't want based on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901958/jquery-on-itself).  A little different from blocking them like I wanted, but effectively the same.  Updated fiddle that shows this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jon_harris7/B4SJP/)